# Script to use SFTP

Tags: shell, unix, sftp

I have an FTP Script as below. And I want the same to be converted to Secured FTP (SFTP) script.

```
FTP_OUT=`ftp -v -n << END_SCRIPT
open $HOST
user $USR $PWD
lcd $LOC_PATH
cd $REM_PATH
mput $FILENM
quit
END_SCRIPT`
```

Suggest the SFTP equivalent of the above FTP script to transfer file from local server to remote server.

Comment: Are you just asking us to do it for you? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: I have never used sftp. It will be good if anyone suggest the changes to the existing ftp script in order to make it sftp. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Maybe the lftp program is worth looking into. I've used it to connect to sftp hosts, but I've never scripted with it

Comment: The code in the question workd fine. But my question here. Is it secured FTP? If not, what makes it secured?

Comment: The S in SFTP means Secure or SSH and it is over port 22 as compared to 21 with FTP. Since SFTP goes over SSH connection, you'll need either a passphrase or public key which encrypt the data transmission, thus making it secure

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scp`

```
scp filename user@host:remote_path
```

This requires you to enter the password. If you want to avoid entering the password every time you use scp, you could generate an authentication key with `ssh-keygen`.